# Azure Analysis Services scale-out via REST API

Tags: rest, azure, azure-analysis-services

is it possible to scaling out azure analysis service via rest api? If yes do have have any idea how can we do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the docs, it seems like it is possible:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/update

As I can see you can set Sku:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/update#resourcesku

And SkuTier:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/analysisservices/servers/update#skutier

So it seems like you can scale up and out also with the API.